# ajax call not responding with $.post

Tags: ajax, jquery

What i am trying to do is to get the value of the selected elements by jquery selection. After that, those value are post to php script via ajax and then retrieve the data from the database and display it on the same page (something called  autocompete).

```
var marvalue=$("input[name=m_status]:checked").val();
var fromhvalue=$("#fromheight").val();
var tohvalue=$("#toheight").val();
var value = $("#edu_det1").val();
alert (value);
var regvalue = $("#religion").val();
alert (regvalue);
var occvalue = $("#occupation").val();
alert (occvalue);
var convalue = $("#country").val();
alert (convalue);
```

Alert is there to check the correct values. As you see the code above this will get the values from the different input elements.
Below is the code i used to post to php

```
/*                              
$.post("regsearch.php", {queryString: ""+value+"",queryString1: ""+marvalue+"",queryStringfage: ""+fage+"",queryStringtage: ""+tage+""+queryStringfromh: ""+fromhvalue+""+queryStringtoh: ""+tohvalue+""+}, function(data) { // Do an AJAX call
            $('#suggestions').fadeIn(); // Show the suggestions box
            $('#suggestions').html(data); // Fill the suggestions box
        });
                                        */
```

**The problem** :

when the comment is removed nor the alert popup and neither the result displayed. Ok about the result as no query is posted.
Major part is that when i use the below code which hold only `m_status` and `edu_det1` it works.

```
marvalue=$("input[name=m_status]:checked").val();
alert (marvalue);

var value = $("#edu_det1").val();

alert (value);
```

The post code for above is

```
$.post("regsearch.php", {
    queryString: ""+value+"",
    queryString1: ""+marvalue+"",
    queryStringfage: ""+fage+"",queryStringtage: ""+tage+""
}, function(data) {
    // Do an AJAX call
    $('#suggestions').fadeIn(); // Show the suggestions box
    $('#suggestions').html(data); // Fill the suggestions box
});
```

The code for age and it verification is not added here. What is the problem and how to sort this out?

Comment: What is querystring? I dont see this anywhere but in $.post()

Comment: querystring contain the value which is read in php script like `$queryString = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use your console to see Javascript errors, as I'm sure this will generate some. For example that querystring is undefined.

I'd also console.log instead of alert, it is less annoying and more informative.

Then: you dont need to use f.e. ""+marvalue+"" - just use marvalue. On the other hand f.e. queryString should be quoted...

```
$.post("regsearch.php", {'queryString':value,'queryString1': marvalue,'queryStringfage':fage,'queryStringtage':tage,'queryStringfromh': fromhvalue,'queryStringtoh':tohvalue}, function(data) { 
            $('#suggestions').fadeIn();
            $('#suggestions').html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you use jquery `serialize()` function. This will make your life easier to work with forms.

```
var querstring = $(form).serialize();
```

above will help

Answer (score 0):

I guess using ajax post jQuery.ajax() will do the same thing and you can even serialize the fields in your page.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

I have done similar type of code

UserName is the field Which I am passing

```
        var data = $('#Username').serialize();
        $('#usernameCheck').empty();

        if (!$("form").validate().element("#Username"))
            return;

        $.ajax({
            url: '/SignUp/CheckUsername',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            async: true,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result == 1) {

                    $('#usernameCheck').html('<font color=green>Username available</font>');
                    usernameOK = true;
                }
                else if (result == 2) {

                    $('#usernameCheck').html('<font color=red>Username not available</font>');
                    usernameOK = false;
                }
                else {
                    $('#usernameCheck').empty();
                    usernameOK = false;
                }

            }
        });
```